# node.js open file overrides existing file

Tags: javascript, c, node.js, file, mmap

i am creating a file in a c like so:

```
int fd;
fd = open(filename, O_RDWR | O_CREAT, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);

if (fd == -1) {
    return NULL;
}

lseek(fd, filesize + 1, SEEK_SET);

write(fd, "", 1);

lseek(fd, 0, SEEK_SET);

void* file_memory = mmap(0, filesize, PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);

close(fd);
```

So, as I said, I create the file and fill it before mapping it in memory.

When i look at the file in the filesystem it gives me 1026 bytes of filesize (simple ls -l from the file)

Later I want to access the file from a node application simple and sound like so:

```
fs.open(filename, 'w', function (err, fd) { ... }
```

When this line is executed the filesize is then set to 0 (again a simple ls -l).

I assume that the file has been recreated? But that should not happen since the file already exists (according to the node.js manual).

What is happening here? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I use the 'w+' flag, it works.

Don't know why because the 'w+' means that it can read and write the file while the 'w' means that it only can write the file.

fs.open(filename, 'w', function (err, fd) { ... }

**EDIT**

From `man fopen`

w

Truncate file to **zero** length or create text file for writing. The stream is positioned at the beginning of the file.

w+

Open for reading and writing. The file is created if it does not exist, otherwise it is truncated. The stream is positioned at the beginning of the file.

Answer (score 0):

You are right, the `w` flag recreates the file. If you want to write at the end of the file, use the `a` (append) flag.